# A positive function which even derivatives are positive and odd derivatives negative

Tags: derivatives, parametric, constraints

Is there any function $f(x)$ which satisfies the following criterion for positive values of $x$ :

- being positive ($f(x)>0$)
- having negative odd derivatives ($f^{2k+1}(x)<0$)
- having positive even derivatives ($f^{2k}(x)\gt0$)

The exponential function $f:x\rightarrow e^{-x}$ does satisfy such conditions but I would like to have a function that could be used to fit some experimental data. Therefore, I want $f(x)$ to have at least 3 parameters that can be adjusted and which optimal values over the experimental data will ensure the previously mentioned inequalities.

For example, $f:x\rightarrow x^{c_1}\exp \left[c_2 (1-x^{c_3})\right]$ has 3 parameters $c_i$ but does not satisfy the constraints previously mentioned for all values of $c_i$ and therefore is not good for me.

Any idea ?

Comment: define "fit" experimental data, what kind of fit exactly? I assume that your data is all positive (or all negative), right? If your data have a spike (local maximum) somewhere then the derivative of some function fitted to a spike necessarily must be positive and negative.

Comment: The $f$ function is part of a big model which is used to represent experimental data so I do not directly fit the $f$ values to the data. Therefore, the experimental data can either be positive or negative. I just know from theoretical considerations that my $f$ function must satisfy the previously mentioned inequalities.

Comment: $f(x)=P(1/x)$ for any  polynomial $P$ of positive degree with non-negative co-efficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a mathematics question at heart, but it has a certain overlap with mathematics.

Such functions are called *completely monotone*, and are characterized by being the Laplace transforms of non-negative distributions. (Look for *Bernstein's theorem*.)

So you could regard your experimental data as measuring the Laplace transform of some unknown non-negative function or measure which you model somehow.  For instance, as a mixture of delta functions with weights and locations you fit, or as a histogram whose bar heights you fit, or as the exponential of a polynomial whose coefficients you fit: something like that.  How you actually do this is certainly not a mathematics problem but rather a question of what makes sense in your application area.  Expect a certain amount of computer huffing and puffing.